# Converting closed form to summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$${x\over 1-x-x^2}$$

This is the closed form for series without coeff of $x^i$ being $F_i$ (ith Fibonacci Number). How can i expand the it without already knowing the series?

For example say we have $${1\over 1+x+x^2}$$
How do i expand it? (without taylor series because it might be difficult to find patterns this way)

Comment: $$1+x+x^2=\dfrac{(1-x^3)}{1-x}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee that was just an example, I was asking how to do it in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to expand $${x\over 1-x-x^2}$$ in a power series?

Begin with
$$x = (1-x-x^2) \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i$$
expand the right side, collect like terms, equate to the left side.  You end up with a recurrence.

Try it!  That way you will learn more than if we just do it for you.

After you do that, maybe try something more general.  Any rational function has an expansion as a power series (perhaps a Laurent series) where the coefficients satisfy a linear recurrence with constant coefficients.

**added**  It seems you tried it but it didn't work out.
Let's go:
\begin{align}
x &= (1-x-x^2) \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i
\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i - x\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i - x^2\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i
\\ &=
\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i - \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^{i+1} - \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^{i+2}
\\ &=
\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i - \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i-1} x^{i} - \sum_{i=2}^\infty a_{i-2} x^{i}
\\ &= a_0 + (a_1-a_0)x
+\sum_{i=2}^\infty (a_i - a_{i-1} - a_{i-2}) x^{i}
\end{align}
Equate terms on the two sides:
\begin{align}
0 &= a_0 \\
1 &= a_1-a_0  \\
0 &= (a_i - a_{i-1} - a_{i-2})\qquad \text{for } i \ge 2
\end{align}
So our power series coefficients satisfy
\begin{align}
a_0 &= 0 \\
a_1 &= 1\\
a_i &= a_{i-1}+a_{i-2}\qquad\text{for }i \ge 2
\end{align}

Comment: Dont really know what Laurent series are, but thanks for the answer! I'll try this out. Can we just assume it is an infinite summation if there's a polynomial in denominator?

Comment: Laurent series: starting at some value other than $i=0$.  For example $$\sum_{i=-7}^\infty a_i x^i$$  You will need this if the denominator of your rational function has constant term zero.

Comment: I simplified it to $$f(x)=a_0+x+\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}(a_{i-1}+a_{i-2})x^i$$  and $a_0$ = 0 by putting $x = 0$ on both sides

Answer (score 1):

For given, $a,b,c,d$ use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

$$\dfrac{ax+b}{1+cx+dx^2}=\dfrac A{1-\alpha x}+\dfrac B{1-\beta x}$$

where $\alpha+\beta=c,\alpha\beta=d, \alpha\ne\beta$ as $\alpha=\beta\implies1+cx+dx^2$ a perfect square.

Now use [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) like $(1-\alpha x)^{-1}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty(\alpha x)^r$ which is readily available from [Geometric Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html)

Comment: For further generality you should have added the case $\alpha=\beta$. :)

Comment: Wouldn't Complex numbers cause this to be way more lengthy and complicated? Gonna try this too

Comment: @user, Thanks :). Perfect won't need this decomposition, right?

Comment: Yep, tried it. It's getting way too out of hand using partial fractions (with complex numbers)